# top frame in the site

Tags: php, html, iframe

hi i want to create a frame in my site like the google image section 
im using php for server side scripting

Comment: is there a question being asked here? Or is this a statement?

Answer (score 2):

Okay.  Create one.

The fact that you're using PHP is irrelevant to creating frames: frames are an HTML construct.  You can create an HTML page with a `<frameset>` at any time, and if the individual frames happen to point to PHP pages that's perfectly fine.

Of course, what you want to display in each frame, and how you want them to interact is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful of frames - they don't always play nice. You might be better off creating a "header" section with html and javascript. This allows users to hide and show the "header" when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the tags that you'll need for using frames within your pages:

```
Tag         Description
<frameset>  Defines a set of frames
<frame>     Defines a sub window (a frame)
<noframes>  Defines a noframe section for browsers that do not handle frames
<iframe>    Defines an inline sub window (frame)
```

These tags are all a part of the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html), but you can use PHP to generate the necessary HTML to display frames in your pages.

*Frames tag information taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_frames.asp)*